# p5js: sending still images through HTTP POST

Tags: image, http, post, format, p5.js

I'm using a simple p5.js programme to take a webcam stream and show a still image from this on the screen every few seconds.

```
let capture;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(320, 240);
    capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
    capture.size(320, 240);
    capture.hide();
   }
function draw() {
    if(frameCount % 120 == 0)
        {image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);}
    }
```

What I want to do then is to take each still image and convert it to a format that I can send using HTTP POST. The online manual is not helpful, and extensive internet searches haven't thrown up anything that works. Any good ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use .toDataURL() to convert the contents of a canvas element to string.
https://editor.p5js.org/EthanHermsey/sketches/bTvntCc35

```
let cnv;
let capture;

function setup() {
  
  cnv = createCanvas(320, 240);
  
  capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
  capture.size(320, 240);
  capture.hide();
  
}


function draw() {
  
  //show live webcam feed
  image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);
  
  if (frameCount % 120 == 0){
    
    captureFrame();
  
  }
}


function captureFrame() {
  
  // convert the graphics canvas to string, you can send that string in a POST request.
  let imageBase64String = cnv.elt.toDataURL();
  
  
  // for example purpose, after you retreive the string from the server with a GET request, 
  // convert it back to an image. 
  
  // let showImg = createImg(imageBase64String, "");
  // showImg.hide();

  // You can use 
  // image( showImg, 0, 0, 320, 240)
  // to draw in on canvas.
  
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ethan. This does just what I needed.